# I'd like the sub menu to appear in a specific place and only when a link is clicked, not hovered over

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

Forgive me for not posting any code, I'm not much of a coder myself though I do get by with a bit of CSS using wordpress themes as a basis. However I'm struggling with something I thought would be relatively simple, and I can't even find an example of it.

Basically, I want a main menu with 6-7 links. When you click a link, it doesn't change the page, it reveals a second menu with a second set of 6-7 links. These links are children of the first link - but they're always displayed in the same place on the page, rather than being physically linked to their parent link. I'll try and explain it better >

So in the Main Menu you have:

A 
B 
C 
D

Then if you click "B", a second menu appears to the right like this:

A B1
B B2
C B3
D B4

Then you can either click on one of the B# links to go to that page, or you can click C and get:

A C1
B C2
C C3
D C4

I know that this probably isn't too difficult, but I'm completely stumped! P.S. if you could work this out for wordpress that would be even better for me but even just html/css would be cool

Please let me know if this makes no sense and I will try to explain it better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do that with CSS. Use JavaScript to alter the css and add event handlers.

Try something like this as a guide using an onclick event handler.
Sorry this is not wordpress code. But try some tweaks in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title></title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 

ul { 
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
list-style-type: none} 

.mainMenus li { 
position: relative} 

.subMenus { 
display: none; 
position: absolute; 
top: 0px; 
left: 120px} 

--> 
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 

window.onload=function() { 
subMenusO = getElementsByClassName(document,'ul','subMenus'); 
} 
//----------------------------------------------------------- 

function showSubMenu(elemId) { 
var dispStatus = (document.getElementById(elemId).style.display == 'block')? 'none' : 'block'; 
//hide any visible submenus 
for(var i=0; i < subMenusO.length; i=i+1) { 
     subMenusO[i].style.display = 'none'; 
    } 
    //show/hide this menu id 
    document.getElementById(elemId).style.display = dispStatus; 
} 
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

function getElementsByClassName(oElm, strTagName, strClassName){ 
    var arrElements = (strTagName == "*" && oElm.all)? oElm.all : oElm.getElementsByTagName(strTagName); 
    var arrReturnElements = new Array(); 
    strClassName = strClassName.replace(/-/g, "\\-"); 
    var oRegExp = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + strClassName + "(\\s|$)"); 
    var oElement; 
    for(var i=0; i<arrElements.length; i++) 
    { 
        oElement = arrElements[i]; 
        if(oRegExp.test(oElement.className)) 
        { 
            arrReturnElements.push(oElement); 
        } 
    } 
    return (arrReturnElements) 
} 

//--> 
</script> 

</head> 
<body> 
<ul class="mainMenus"> 
    <li onclick='showSubMenu("sm_item1")'> 
     Main menu 1 
          <ul class="subMenus" id="sm_item1" > 
                 <li>Sub menu 1 item 1</li> 
                 <li>Sub menu 1 item 2</li> 
                 <li>Sub menu 1 item 3</li> 
                 <li>Sub menu 1 item 4</li> 
          </ul> 
    </li> 
    <li onclick='showSubMenu("sm_item2")'> 
     Main menu 2 
            <ul class="subMenus" id="sm_item2"> 
                  <li>Sub menu 2 item 1</li> 
                   <li>Sub menu 2 item 2</li> 
             </ul> 
    </li> 
</ul> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. I had a problem with the cursor not changing to a hand but I added mainMenus li{ cursor: pointer; } and that's solved it. I haven't had a chance to go much further with it yet so hopefully it will work but it's exactly what I wanted, so thanks!